# Debug issue of high DNS Loopkup Time for Route 53 with Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have setup elastic beanstalk (with load balancer) node js instance On Amazon Linux 2.
Using Route 53 to manage DNS.

This is the network timing screenshot from Chrome.
I think the DNS lookup time is too high. It should be less than 50ms since I am using a reputed DNS service.

[image: api response time]

#### Questions

1. Is more than 300ms of DNS lookup time very high? Should I simply ignore?
2. Is there any way to debug the issue, as to what is causing this high time?
3. I should investigate Eleastic beanstalk or route 53 for this issue?

#### More details

1. Yes, it happens on every request

#### Route 53 Config

[image: route 53 config]

Comment: Is it like that on every lookup? The first lookup after a while? One off? Can you share how you've set it up in Route 53?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, have added details

Comment: Are you also based in `ap-south-1`? Use https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check DNS lookup time worldwide - is it still 300ms?

Comment: It does not show Lookup Time. Yes, I am based in ap-south-1

Comment: Do you have another device to test with? It sounds like a local DNS server issue

Comment: Set your DNS config to primary 1.1.1.1, secondary 1.0.0.1 and retry - does the lookuptime improve?

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggestions shared by @ErmiyaEskandary

1. Change local DNS
2. Test on another ISP
3. Test at different time of the Day
4. Ask my colleague to test from different city

Still the DNS lookup was between 250 to 380ms.

Solution which finally worked
Instead of pointing Route 53 to Elastic bean stalk, should have pointed it to Load balancer.

[image: router 53 config for elastic beanstalk]

New Network Timing screenshot after the change.

[image: netwrk]